# Not playing MJPEG streaming in mobile browsers (tag <img>)

Tags: html, image, mobile, stream, mjpeg

May be someone knows how to play a MJPEG stream on mobile browsers (Windows Phone, Android)?

The tag `<img id="mjpeg" src="http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg" alt="">` does not work.

Comment: By using Chrome Browser on Android it works. No luck on Windows Phone, sadly. I am also VERY interested in streaming mjpeg to Windows Phone's browser but I didn't find any solution yet.